# Test Class for triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, test-automation

I am new to salesforce and i am writing a test class for the trigger. Can any one tell me how to write a test class for the trigger below

```
trigger CloseParentCommunication on BuyerSellerCommunication__c (before insert,after insert,before update,after update) {

    List<ID> parentCommId = New List<ID>();

    for(seit__BuyerSellerCommunication__c communication:Trigger.new)
    {

        if(communication.seit__Status__c=='Closed' && communication.seit__Parent_Communication__c!=Null)
        {
            parentCommId.add(communication.seit__Parent_Communication__c);
        }
    }

    List<seit__BuyerSellerCommunication__c> parentCommList = [SELECT id,name,status__c FROM seit__BuyerSellerCommunication__c WHERE id in :parentCommId];
    for(integer i = 0 ; i < parentCommList .size(); i++){
        parentCommList[i].status__c = 'Closed';
        update parentCommList[i];
    }

    update parentCommList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I don't want to write test class for your trigger but I can guide you

```
@isTest 
private class Test_CloseParentCommunication  {
    static testMethod void testCloseParentCommunication() {
       // first insert your seit__BuyerSellerCommunication__c records here.. with all required values like name, status__c etc

       // now create seit__BuyerSellerCommunication__c  records with required fields. Perform insert DML that will fire the trigger
      // If all the condition satisfies in trigger 
      // like  seit__BuyerSellerCommunication__c.seit__Status__c  = 'closed'
      // then update parent record ie.e seit__BuyerSellerCommunication__c  status update 
       // put system.assert to check parent status changed or not
      // perform update operation and update status field  
      // after update put system.assert to check parent status changed or not
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic premise is that you need to create & manipulate test data in order to have your trigger run, then assert that the logic has acted correctly.

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_To_Test_Your_Apex_Triggers) is an excellent article on testing trigger logic.

> When deploying your Apex development from a sandbox to a production environment (Apex trigger, Apex class, etc.), Salesforce
>   requires 75% code coverage, and the execution of that code must not
>   incur any development errors. This article will show how to develop an
>   Apex test class to cover your Apex development, and ensure the code
>   performs correctly. Specifically, this article will show how to:
>
> 1. Develop an Apex trigger that will run itself during the creation and
>      modification of a Case record.
> 2. Create a test class to test the trigger code.
> 3. Test a web service call and simulate its response.

So in your scenario you will need to insert / update some BuyerSellerCommunication__c records in order to match your trigger criteria, then requery the dataset to ensure the trigger has run & set the Status__c field accordingly.

Also, as you're new to Salesforce it would be a good idea to read up on the basics and implement a nice framework from the get-go. [Here](http://davincasey.com/my-preferred-apex-trigger-framework/) is my preferred approach.